# tod_detecting output

Tags: ros, tod-training, tod-detecting, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using tod_training and tod_detecting packages for object detection and recognition. They work well but the output is just an image of estimated pose and the name of the recognized object.

My question is how can I find this estimated pose? Not just by seeing on the image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9110/tod_detecting-output/) by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-15**:
Would it be possible for you to post a patch?

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-14**:
Diamondback. But debugged the code myself

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-03**:
Ho, may I ask what did you compile it with? (Cturlte, Unstable, Diamondback?) I'm having a few compilation issues myself.

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-02**:
yes I am using it on its own. Actually I trained some objects from bag files with tod_training and than I detect those object from images or camera recordings using tod_detecting. I can get estimated pose visually on the input image I gave but I can't take it numerically. It computes it somewhere..

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-01**:
Hello, are you using tod on its own or via the Recognition Infrastructure (ReIn) ?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-28**:
How you run tod_training and tod_detecting? Can you share instructions? I can't find tutorials on package doc. Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running the recognizer node from tod_detecting and are seeing text output like

```
 "Object name = " << object.objectName << ", imageId = " << object.imgIdx
```

then that is generated from line 167 of [recognizer.cpp](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tod_detecting/html/recognizer_8cpp_source.html#l00167).

Each of the ObjectInfo objects referenced there have rvec and tvec members (see [this](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tod_detecting/html/structtod_1_1ObjectInfo.html)) which presumably store the pose of the object. You could modify that loop to print out or otherwise output the pose as well as the name.

---

Originally posted by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) with karma: 226 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-03**:
Is tvec the translation vector camera frame to object frame and the rvec is the rotation vector from from object coordinate frame to camera coordinate frame? And what rvec exactly shows? radians? And angle changes with respect to which axises?